# Pygame - No file found in working directory

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame

from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

screen_width = 800
screen_height = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Platformer')

#load images

bg_img = pygame.image.load("img/sky.png")


run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    screen.blit(bg_img, (0,0))

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Whenever I try and do This It come up as an Error such as this

```
FileNotFoundError: No file 'img/sky.png' found in working directory 'C:\Users\yeg20\OneDrive\Desktop\workspace'.
```

Could anyone tell me why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: The error means what it says. Does `img\sky.png` exist within `C:\Users\yeg20\OneDrive\Desktop\workspace` or not? Fix it by putting the file in the correct location

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to load an image at the relative path `img/sky.png`. Your working directory is currently `C:\Users\yeg20\OneDrive\Desktop\workspace`. You do not have a file at `C:\Users\yeg20\OneDrive\Desktop\workspace\img\sky.png`

Comment: So how do I fix this

Comment: @YegorTarasov - Either specify the full path to the file, perhaps using `os.path.join()`, or move the `sky.png` to `C:\Users\yeg20\OneDrive\Desktop\workspace\img\`